# Python 3 and-or vs if-else

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, operators, logical-operators

Is there any difference between the following?

```
print(x if x else 'no x available')
# compared to:
print(x and x or 'no x available')
```

Comment: Difference is that the first one is readable.

Comment: /me Waiting for someone to use [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#module-dis).

Comment: Wait, you forgot `['no x available', x][bool(x)]` *ducks*

Comment: Just as a note, the old "and-or" idiom failed in `x and y or z` situations compared to `y if x else z`, if y was falsy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In practice they are the same; in theory they are different, but only when the `__bool__` method has side effects:

```
>>> class Weird:
    state = False
    def __bool__(self):
        self.state = not self.state
        return self.state


>>> x = Weird(); print(x if x else 'no x available')
<__main__.Weird object at 0x0000000003513160>
>>> x = Weird(); print(x and x or 'no x available')
no x available
```

If you run into this theoretical case you have worse problems to worry about.

Also note that:

```
>>> x = Weird(); print(x or 'no x available')
<__main__.Weird object at 0x00000000035071D0>
```

so Klass Ivan's answer is technically wrong.

Bottom line, use the `if` expression as that expresses what you mean much more clearly.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was hoping for; actual differences in how they act (I know, I should've asked bit more clearly). Thanks for the answer though! :)

Comment: Yeah! Just realized that point and come back for edits and you've already demonstrated what I want also to add - the only difference can be when `__bool__(self)` method is not "pure function".

Answer (score 10):

Both lines are same as:

```
print(x or 'no x available')
```

About second alternative:
Always keep in mind, that according to operator precedence `and` is evaluated first, so it first calculates `x and x`, which is totally useless - it equals `x`

Comment: ideone's python compiles your code to a different byte code than OP's version co I would not be so sure if one can say they are the same.

Comment: could you please compile `return x and x and x and x and x` and `return x` (there is no doubt they're same). Will they differ in bytecode?

Comment: http://ideone.com/e7LFCy It seems like default python interpreter does not perform much optimization.

Comment: I accidentally choose python2 there, but I just checked that everything holds for python3. I can use my local machine python and give you results somehow.

Comment: Check my somewhat tongue-in-cheek answer: `x and x or 'no x available'` and `x or 'no x available'` could be different in pathological cases.

Answer (score 5):

Running this:

```
import dis
def f1():
  print(x if x else 'no x available')
def f2():
  print(x and x or 'no x available')
def f3():
  print(x or 'no x available')
dis.dis(f1)
dis.dis(f2)
dis.dis(f3)
```

We get, for `f1`:

```
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              9 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 15)
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('no x available')
        >>   15 PRINT_ITEM          
             16 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

For `f2`:

```
  7           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              9 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     15
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('no x available')
        >>   15 PRINT_ITEM          
             16 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

For `f3` taken from @Klass Ivan:

```
 10           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP      9
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('no x available')
        >>    9 PRINT_ITEM          
             10 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

So `f1` and `f2` are not the same. They do have different logic, as Klass mentions. `f3` and `f1` versions also differ, even though logically they should be equivalent, `f3` spares some operations.

Comment: Be accurate - `9 JUMP_FORWARD`  vs  `9 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP` - f1 and f2 aren't same.

Comment: @KlassIvan I noticed it and edited it. Thanks for pointing it out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Code-wise I think this has been covered but I would note that what you're doing here is linguistically very different and is likely to have a very different effect on people reading your code, and perhaps the subconscious of those merely navigating front-end of the website (people with even a passing involvement with or knowledge of code may find themselves psychologically influenced by the underlying 'symbolic links'*). To break this down further, let's consider a string value for `x`:

```
var x = "spoon";
print(x if x else 'no x available')
# compared to:
print(x and x or 'no x available')
```

It's still difficult to see exactly what will happen to "spoon" here, so to make things clearer we could just call our variable "hasSpoon" instead of assigning it a string (but you can believe we've assigned it a string of "spoon" too if you like...):

```
print(hasSpoon if hasSpoon is true else 'no hasSpoon available')
# compared to:
print(hasSpoon and hasSpoon or 'no hasSpoon available')
```

As we can see, in the first instance the logical reading would be that our metaphorical cutlery wielder has a spoon if they have a spoon, which I think we will probably agree on (and on the other hand they have the condition of not having a spoon available to them, rather than not actually having a spoon which is a little odd, but possible, but let's leave it aside for now.)

In the second expression the logical implication is rather that our theoretical diner has a spoon and also has a spoon, which is tautological in a whole other way.

So, if you wanted to express to any would-be readers of the code, and also anyone who might be potentially influenced by it by-proxy, that people who have spoons are very likely to have spoons, and those that don't have the option to not have a spoon, you would use the first option. If, on the other hand, you wished to express that a particular person both has a spoon and has a spoon, or else they have the condition of not having a spoon open to them, you would use the second expression.

Or something.

*I use the term symbolically here, if you'll pardon the pun.